# My AJAX responses are getting downloaded rather than getting loaded in success data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am quiet new to JQuery. I am sending an AJAX request (File Upload) to WEB API (ASP.NET MVC) but my responses are getting downloaded as JSON file rather than the loaded to success data.

Please find the code in the HTML below

```
 $('#myForm1')[0].submit(function (event) {
            alert("Hello2");
            event.preventDefault();
            //grab all form data  
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            alert("Hello2");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:102/webapi/api/values/All',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                datatype : "json",
                //async: false,
                //cache: false,
                contentType: true,
                processData: false,
                complete: function () {
                    alert("Complete");
                },
                success: function (returndata) {
                   // $("#productFormOutput").html(returndata);
                    alert("Executed");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error in ajax form submission");
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

[image]

BTW no alert messages in success, error and complete is called after getting the response. But Fiddler shows the response is successful (HTTP 200). Is anything am I doing wrong while calling the request?

Comment: Hi Roland.If I am not using the [0], my form submit is not getting called itself. If I use [0] only I am getting the request and I can able to debug the request in my VS.

Comment: So you are not submiting the form with a button? Because` $('#myForm1')[0].submit()` submits a form and ` $('#myForm1').submit(fn)` registers an event handler.

Comment: Here is the function you call https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit. So not even  "Hello2" should be alerted.

Comment: Hi Roland, Thanks.. removing the [0] solved this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing [0] and changing the input to 'submit' in form solved my problem

```
$('#myForm1')[0].submit(function (event)
```

As Roland said, submit with button in  input tag is not handling the event handler

Answer (score 0):

try using "done" method as the success handler instead of "success",

and instead of alert use console log(you can check the log on the browser, ctrl+shift+I on chrome, you can even put object to be logged).
after several times alert my be blocked by browser as it is annoying.

easy and complete reference: https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

*what is the complete method doing in that post object ?